# Fraction rounding in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Can somebody explain result of this SQL query?

```
select 
                 (1/3)*30  x1,
        to_number(1/3)*30  x2,
  floor(         (1/3)*30) x3,
  floor(to_number(1/3)*30) x4
from dual;
```

And results are:

```
X1      X2      X3      X4
10      10      10       9
```

**Edit**

What about this one? Difference in one digit...

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT
        0.333333333333333333333333333333333333333  digits_39,
        0.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333 digits_40
    FROM dual
)
SELECT

    digits_39*30                     digits_39_1,
    FLOOR(digits_39*30)              digits_39_2,
    FLOOR(         (digits_39)*30)   digits_39_3,
    FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(digits_39)*30)   digits_39_4,

    digits_40*30                      digits_40_1,
    FLOOR(digits_40*30)               digits_40_2,
    FLOOR(         (digits_40)*30)    digits_40_3,
    FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(digits_40)*30)    digits_40_4

FROM test;
```

And result:

```
DIGITS_39_1     DIGITS_39_2     DIGITS_39_3     DIGITS_39_4
         10               9               9               9
DIGITS_40_1     DIGITS_40_2     DIGITS_40_3     DIGITS_40_4
         10              10              10               9
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer is simple.
 `(1/3) * 30` When interpreted as `30 / 3` Gives `10`.

This is what happened with your **1st** and **3rd** expressions. As the processor had it as fractions but not decimals.

But when seen as decimals like `(0.3333) * 30` it gives `9.999`

When you isolated (1/3) and adding `to_number()` to it..There's a loss of precision here

It just gave you `0.333333` and hence `0.333333 * 30 = 9.9999`

And `FLOOR(9.9999) = 9` (Rounded to the least integer value)

---

**EDIT:**

Interesting thing here is.(the *2nd* Expression,`to_number(1/3)*30`)

**SQL Developer**, 
Gives output as,

[image]

But **SQL*Plus**, gives as,

```
        X1         X2         X3         X4 TO_NUMBER(1/3)
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------
        10         10         10          9     .333333333
```

---

Finally, From [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020).

> Oracle guarantees the portability of numbers with precision of up to
>   20 base-100 digits, which is equivalent to 39 or 40 decimal digits
>   depending on the position of the decimal point.

So, greater to it is simply rounded. You can try replacing 30 with 3 and you can check it.

You have 39 decimal digits in first and 40 in the second.